# MySQL Combining FULLTEXT with a LIKE Fallback

Tags: php, mysql

I'm building my app to use a single search table for searching all different object types ie: posts, pages, products etc., based on [this article.](http://www.mullie.eu/mysql-as-a-search-engine/)

My table layout looks like so:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myapp_search_index (
  id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  language_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(24) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  object_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `text` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (id,language_id),
  FULLTEXT KEY `text.fdx` (`text`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

My search query looks like so:

```
$items = $db->escape($query);

$query = $db->query("
    SELECT *, 
    SUM(MATCH(text) AGAINST('+{$items}' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) as score 
    FROM {$db->prefix}search_index 
    WHERE MATCH(text) AGAINST('+{$items}' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
    GROUP BY language_id, type, object_id 
    ORDER BY score DESC 
    LIMIT " . (int)$start . ", " . (int)$limit . "
");
```

This works great except where we run into fulltext limitations like stop words and min word length.

For instance I have 2 entries in the table for my `About Us` page, one holds the page title, and one holds the content of the page.

Running the query `about us` returns no results as `about` is a stop word, and `us` is less than the minimum 4 letters.

So, my thought was to create a conditional fallback query using a traditional `LIKE` parameter as such:

```
if (!$query->num_rows):
    $query = $db->query("
        SELECT * 
        FROM {$db->prefix}search_index 
        WHERE text LIKE '%{$items}%' 
        GROUP BY language_id, type, object_id 
        ORDER BY id DESC 
        LIMIT " . (int)$start . ", " . (int)$limit . "
    ");
endif;
```

And once again this works fine. My `About Us` page now comes up just fine in the results.

But what I'd like is to run this all in one query and maintain the score somehow.

Is this possible?

EDIT:

Ok so in response to Michael's answer and comments I've changed my query to this:

```
SELECT *, 
SUM(MATCH(text) AGAINST('{$search}' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) as score 
FROM {$db->prefix}test_index 
WHERE (
    MATCH(text) AGAINST('{$search}' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
    AND text LIKE '%{$search}%') 
OR text LIKE '%{$search}%' 
GROUP BY language_id, type, object_id 
ORDER BY score DESC
```

I set up a test table with 100K rows, 50K of which do contain my `lorem ipsum` search term.

This queries the entire table and returns results in 0.6379 microseconds without any query caching as of yet.

Can anyone tell me if this seems like a fair compromise?

Comment: both stop words and min length are changeable

Comment: True but this is for a public application and not all users will have the ability to adjust their `my.cnf` file.

Comment: fulltext in mysql needs plenty of data too and not that sophisticated anyway

Comment: I'm assuming that most entries will have a decent amount of data, but of course that's up to the end users and their needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play around with natural language mode too with multi-word:

```
SELECT id,prod_name, match( prod_name )
AGAINST ( '+harpoon +article' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) AS relevance
FROM testproduct 
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

We often just go with `solr` integration, throwing json csv and text files at it.

Comment: I plan on integrating Sphinx as the preferred search method, but once again, since this is for public use not everyone will be able to install it, so I'd like to work out a really tight default search that non-ssh users can still get really good results with.

Comment: Perhaps monetize that concept and have that set up for them turnkey. I naturally do not know your particulars, but they have http and you're a coder ;)

Comment: Nice.  Good idea, thanks Drew. Do you think I should just go with what I have then, or is there an elegant way to combine these queries?

Comment: I think that only Vince is going to know based of your happiness factor of the results. And the jury is still out on that one. I know that I wouldn't combine them. I would spend that time using something that was meant for search and darn good at it.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to elegantly combine fulltext search and `LIKE` together to get *more* results.

This is because the two predicates would have to be combined with an `OR`, which would in turn mean a full table scan (or full index scan if a suitable `BTREE` exists) is required to test the `LIKE` expression.  All rows would have to be evaluated, which would remove any optimization you're getting from the fulltext search.

In the opposite situation, combining `MATCH` and `LIKE` using `AND` instead of `OR` -- in cases where the fulltext match returns insufficiently precise matches -- works great because the optimizer uses the fulltext index to find all possible matching rows, then filters the identified rows against the `LIKE` expression.  (Fulltext indexes are almost always preferred by the optimizer, when other possible query plans exist.)   Unfortunately, that's the opposite of what you need.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Could you possibly give some example code on your second paragraph, using `MATCH` and `LIKE` with `AND`?

Comment: @VinceKronlein that would be `SELECT ... WHERE MATCH (column1) AGAINST (...) AND column1 LIKE '%string%';`.  This will always return the same number or fewer results as the fulltext query by itself.  It can never return more results since the `WHERE` clause is more restrictive.

Comment: Hey thanks Michael.  So when using `SELECT ... WHERE MATCH (column1) AGAINST (...) OR column1 LIKE '%string%';` you say I'd lose optimization, would this make a huge difference if I'm only querying a single table? I wouldn't imagine that this table would have more than 20-40K rows.

Comment: It's not ideal, but if the table is relatively small, it might perform acceptably; however, that will be a subjective call on your part. Regarding the updated question, adding the `AND ... LIKE` doesn't give you any real benefit that I can see, unless you are indeed getting spurious matches that need to be filtered, since the subsequent `OR` guarantees that any rows matched by the first part will also be matched by the `LIKE` all on its own... other than, perhaps, the "score."