# search in mysql, php, find all words that contain 'str'

Tags: php, mysql

What I'm trying to do is to display all possible variations in the table on the screen. If `$search = str`, to search in the table for every word which contains 'str' in it. I tried a lot of variations to do it, but without success yet. What is wrong, and can i use something like `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE * LIKE '[[:<:]]\"$search\"[[:>:]]' "` ?

```
$string = "SELECT * FROM table

WHERE (column1 = '[[:<:]]\"$search\"[[:>:]]') 
OR (column2 = '[[:<:]]\"$search\"[[:>:]]')
OR (column3 = '[[:<:]]\"$search\"[[:>:]]') 
OR (column4 = '[[:<:]]\"$search\"[[:>:]]')
OR (column6 = '[[:<:]]\"$search\"[[:>:]]')  
OR (column7 = '[[:<:]]\"$search\"[[:>:]]')";
```

**Question: find all words that contain 'str'**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What is the result of your posted code?

Comment: This smells a bit "search enginey" to me ... and if they were easy Google wouldn't be gazillionaires! Take a look at Solr : http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

Comment: @kittykittybangbang it is showing nothing.

Comment: @CD001 yea actually search engine is what i'm trying to do, but a simple one xax

Comment: full text search one column, or solr http://stackoverflow.com/a/31127600/1816093 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/30677347/1816093

Comment: The simplest way to do it, with MySQL, is to use a MYISAM table with a FULLTEXT index on it to retrieve the results by relevance - then parse those results down to the values you want; weirdly it's better to have MySQL fetch *more* than you need initially and then have PHP filter it rather than made a really complex SQL query - it works out quicker. Take a look at Natural Language Searches in MySQL : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

Comment: it may be simple. but getting results you want aren't. rollup up your sleeves with fulltext, stop words, ranking, and then go to solr anyway

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

First, get all the columns in database who contains `$str`like this :

`"SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE UPPER(your_field) LIKE UPPER('%" . $str . "%')";`

After,

Parse this results to find the `$str` in words.

Like this :

`$explode = explode($results);`

Then you use `strpos();` and `strstr();` combined to match `$str` in your array

Some function like this :

`function getMultiPos($haystack, $needles, $sensitive=true, $offset=0){
    foreach($needles as $needle) {
        $result[$needle] = ($sensitive) ? strpos($haystack, $needle, $offset) : stripos($haystack, $needle, $offset);
    }
    return $result;
}`

[Source](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strpos.php#116062)

Comment: The question is to find all **words** that contain the substring - not all columns

Comment: So you get ALL the columns who contains THIS word and after we parse the result to extract all word who contains THIS word. I edit my answer thx @CD001

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `column1 LIKE '%str%'` as condition

Comment: The question is to find all **words** that contain the substring - not all columns